# requiring namespaces in clojure leinengen project

Tags: clojure, namespaces, jvm, leiningen

I'm new with clojure and the jvm and am having trouble creating a leinengen project where I can separate my code into namespaces. My project is named cloj_test and in my cloj_test/src/cloj_test directory I have a file named db_connect.clj. In the db_connect.clj file I have code at the top to define the namespace

```
(ns db-connect
(:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
          [clojure.java.jdbc.sql :as sql]))
```

and then a few functions to define some database functionality. cloj_test/src is on the lein classpath. When I launch the repl using "lein repl" and then type

```
(require 'cloj-test.db-connect)
```

It works. However, if I type

```
(require '[cloj-test.db-connect :as db])
```

I get this error:

```
Exception namespace 'cloj-test.db-connect' not found  clojure.core/load-lib (core.clj:5380)
```

The same thing happens when I use "use". Does anybody know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package name is missing form the ns declaration

```
(ns cloj-test.db-connect
(:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
          [clojure.java.jdbc.sql :as sql]))
```

The namespace declaration needs to match the directory that the file is in
(except that `-`s are changed to `_`s) in the file and directory names.